# Inferring return type of form.getValues is incorrect

Tags: typescript, generics, react-hook-form

I was under the impression that `ReturnType` gave the return type, but for `react-hook-form` it doesn't seem to be working as shown in my example below.

```js
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
...
const form = useForm({
  defaultValues: { email: "" },
});

type MyFormType = ReturnType<typeof form.getValues>; // type MyFormType = string[]
const value = form.getValues(); // const value: { email: string; }

// they aren't the same type. Why?
const typedValue: MyFormType = value; // Type '{ email: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 31 more.
```

Also, for me, extracting the default values to a local variable isn't acceptable. In my environment, I only have access to the `form` variable.

My goal is to infer the type of the form state without declaring a type. I need to just infer it instead of declaring the type.

What am I doing wrong?